# UITextView in UITableViewCell how to scroll table view to keep cursor visible while typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a custom UITableViewCell which contains a UITextView. The cell is fairly large. How can I autoscroll the table to ensure the current selection point is always visible?

Note the UITextView is the size of the cell so it won't autoscroll itself.

I can call firstRectForRange on the selectedTextRange, but this doesn't work if the insertion point is at the end (you get inf,inf,0,0 for the CGRect). If I had the rect I could calculate the offset in the table and adjust its scroll contentOffset. is there a good way to do this or is messing with the contentOffset the only way?

Answer (score 3):

use this in the textviewdidchange

```
if let confirmedTextViewCursorPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.end {

            let caretPosition = textView.caretRect(for: confirmedTextViewCursorPosition)
            var textViewActualPosition = tableView.convert(caretPosition, from: textView.superview?.superview)
            textViewActualPosition.origin.y += 20.0 // give the actual padding of textview inside the cell
            tableView.scrollRectToVisible(textViewActualPosition, animated: false)

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

any luck on this? I',m having trouble with the exact same situation. What I',m currently doing is getting the rect of the caret position by using

```
[textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.end]
```

then trying to compute from

```
convertRect: fromView:
```